# C++ std::thread passing member function inside current class

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am trying to make a thread call passing a member function. The problem is that I make the call inside another member function of the same class. What I mean:

```
class A {
   void foo(int a);

   void bar() {
       int k = 2;
       thread t(&A::foo, this, k);
   }
}
```

I also tried to pass `this` as reference: `&this` or `std::ref(this)` without any success. What exactly is my mistake?

**EDIT:** Below is the actual code that gives me the error

```
class SUBTHREAD {
public:
    SUBTHREAD(const SOCKET client, const int ID, MAINTHREAD *Server);

    void handleQFStreaming(const vector<string> &splitMessage);
    void handleIncoming(const string &message, const int &length);
    void run();

private:
    MAINTHREAD *Server;
    SOCKET client;
    vector<thread> QFSThreads;
    int ID;

};

void SUBTHREAD::handleQFStreaming(const vector<string> &splitMessage) {
     ...
}

void SUBTHREAD::handleIncoming(const string &message, const int &length) {
     ...
     QFSThreads.push_back(thread(&SUBTHREAD::handleQFStreaming, this, splitMessage));
     ...
}
```

**EDIT:** The entire error I get is:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: BankServer, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  bserver.cpp
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0(593): error C2280: 'std::thread::thread(const std::thread &)' : attempting to reference a deleted function
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\thread(70) : see declaration of 'std::thread::thread'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0(592) : while compiling class template member function 'void std::allocator<_Ty>::construct(_Ty *,const _Ty &)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=std::thread
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0(723) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::allocator<_Ty>::construct(_Ty *,const _Ty &)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=std::thread
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\type_traits(572) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::allocator<_Ty>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=std::thread
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\vector(650) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::is_empty<_Alloc>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Alloc=std::allocator<std::thread>
1>          ]
1>          e:\programming\workspace\visual studio 2013\projects\bankserver\bankserver\bserver.h(63) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::vector<std::thread,std::allocator<_Ty>>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=std::thread
1>          ]
1>  Generating Code...
1>  Compiling...
1>  main.cpp
1>  Generating Code...
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79072/discussion-on-question-by-dchatzis-c-stdthread-passing-member-function-insid).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem is

```
vector<thread> QFSThreads;
```

It is not allowed to copy a std::thread.

@see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/thread/thread/thread/

Comment: But `std::thread`s can be moved: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/828b532f440d89d0

Comment: But I don't copy it, I just declare it